# How to bind ConcurrentDictionary with WPF ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding

I don't have much experience with ListView nor with binding.

I have ConcurrentDictionary

Where the key is long, and Test is a class that has several public attributes.

I want to have a list view with columns showing some of those attributes (no editing is required), and when a user selects an item from the list, can access the corresponding Test object.

I want to make sure also that the operations would be thread-safe as I am using a Concurrent Dictionary where tasks can add items to it at anytime.

I am using .Net Framework 4.5, Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: When you bind to a collection where items are added dynamically you need to use a collection that implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged.aspx) interface, like [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Write value converter for this. On items adding you can just notify whole dict view model (which implements **INotifyPropertyChanged**) property changed and list will be repopulated. But you can wrap ConcurrentDictionary in your collection which implements **INotifyCollectionChanged**. 
Examples: [here](https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/browser/Nuclex.Support/trunk/Source/Collections/ObservableDictionary.cs?rev=1473) and [here](https://www.cryptool.org/trac/CrypTool2/browser/trunk/CrypPlugins/WorkspaceManager/View/Base/ObservableDictionary.cs?rev=2832)